# BottomNavigationView overlaps the content-android

Tags: android

i have created a activity with collapsing toolbar, but now i have added a bottom navigation view with 3 menu items in it.
but i noticed that, the content displayed in activity is hiding behind the bottom navigation view.
anyone having idea?
in short, the last some lines of my content layout are hiding behind bottom navigation view.

here is my xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="@drawable/p1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" /> 


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:padding="16dp"

        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_above="@+id/navigationbottom"
Insert this line at your view